# edge - why is opendns issuing the certificate for bing.com?

Tags: security, microsoft-edge, internet-security, trusted-root-certificates

[image: screenshot]

Doesn't microsoft sign their own sites? Did malware install a fake certificate?

Comment: What browser are you using? What did you type into the url box?

Comment: What is the NET:ERR... error behind the certificate window?

Comment: odd, the common name when I view the cert is r.bin.com, issued by Microsoft Corporation, Common Name: "Microsoft Azure ECC TLS Issuing CA 05" - the fact that the cert you're looking at is issued TO openDNS inc is interesting

Comment: @JaromandaX  Is r.bin.com a typo?

Comment: You have your network configuration to use [Cisco Umbrella](https://umbrella.cisco.com/) which is a legitimate security product. **The certificate is signed by Cisco not OpenDNS** Talk to your Administrator about the current configuration of your network

Comment: @OskarSkog - yeah, it's r.bing.com :p